# checking partcular filed in a response in spring cloud contact creation

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

Is there any way to test only particular field in a response is matching with the given text or not while writing a contract using spring-cloud-contract framework.

```
package contracts
import org.springframework.cloud.contract.spec.Contract

Contract.make {

request {
    method 'GET'
    url value(consumer(regex('/app/emp/employee/[0-9]{3}')), producer('/app/emp/employee/151'))
}

response {
    status 200
    body([
            subjectsList: null,
            errorResponse: null,
            status: 'success',
            employeeList: null,
            Employee: [
                EmployeeId: 151,
                firstName: 'xxx',
                lastName: 'xxx',
                middleName: 'xxx',
                dateOfBirth: 01012001,
                status: 'inbound',
                cin: '345',
                ssn: null,
                EmployeeType: 'HoH',
                preferredLanguage: 'french',
                preferredContactMethod: null,
                createdBy: null,
                creadtedOn: null,
                updatedBy: null,
                updatedOn: null,
                transactionId: null
            ],
            paginated: null
    ])
    headers {
        header('Content-Type': value(
                producer(regex('application/json.*')),
                Employee('application/json')
        ))
    }
}
```

}

Instead of writing complete response, Is there any way to check only particular attribute present in the response for ex: language = 'french'

Thanks in advance, your help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just remove all the other fields. Whatever you put in the body will get asserted. BTW what you do with the contract looks like a schema. If a field is null that means that it has to be there and it has to be null or rather it's optional?

If you want to do any custom assertion on the part of / whole body you can use this http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Dalston.SR4/multi/multi__contract_dsl.html#_dynamic_properties_in_matchers_sections and pass any jsonpath element for custom assertion

BTW for the response you can write `headers { contentType(applicationJson()) }`